# how can I get the radius of a curve circle from the Object Info?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to catch the radius of a curve circle in Geometry Nodes,
from the "Object Info" node ?

I've seen there is an Input > Radius node, but I need to get that data outside the curve circle itself.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

ok, sorry, you have to divide it by 2....but i think you can do that ;)

Comment: I think they meant the radius attribute that's tied to each control point

Comment: ah...ok....i think you are right

Comment: ok...he checked as ok...so i think you are wrong :D